# Character encoding Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I've been trying to print a Unicode character in Python 3, but it just doesn't work, I've been looking for a solution here on stackoverflow but nothing works. I have something like this.

```
print('This is a Unicode character: Ⱥ')
```

But I got this error message:

[image]

I know that Python 3 uses UTF-8 as default encoding, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @vaultah Nope, you can see there says "Python34"

Comment: The console you try to print on, cannot handle the character `Ⱥ`, because it uses cp850-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To print Unicode characters correctly, you need these things:

1. Python must know the source encoding to understand non-ASCII characters in the source code.  Python 3 assumes UTF-8 unless told otherwise with a special comment at the top of the file, such as `#coding: cp850`.  Note that the source encoding and the terminal encoding don't have to be the same, and it is fine to use UTF-8 for the source encoding as long as the source file is actually *saved* in UTF-8.
2. The Unicode character must be supported by the console's encoding.
3. The Unicode character must be supported by the console's font.
4. Use Unicode strings. In Python 3 `'string'` is a Unicode string.  `b'string'` is a byte string.

Since your error message indicates the console is using [Code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), you will get a `UnicodeEncodeError` if you try to print any characters not supported by that code page.

Try this.  These are legal `cp850` characters:

```
print('╔═╦═╗')
print('║ ║ ║')
print('╠═╬═╣')
print('║ ║ ║')
print('╚═╩═╝')
```

This should work for Python 3 on any console/IDE that supports line-draw characters.  The US Windows console uses `cp437` and European Windows often uses `cp850`, but both define the characters and the console font supports them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized that it is in fact problem of cmd's code page encoding, so, I just change it using CHCP command and UTF-8 code "65001" and it works, but when I close and open cmd again, is not active anymore, and I don't know how to keep it permanently.

Comment: That code page is buggy on Windows. Better to use an IDE that supports UTF8 instead.